# Error trying to declare my fluxible react.js component in an es6 class

Tags: reactjs, fluxible

I'm getting this error trying to create my fluxible component with an es6 class declaration:

```
Warning: getInitialState was defined on SearchResults,
a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for 
classes created using React.createClass. Did you mean 
to define a state property instead?
```

I'm going off of this example on the fluxible docs:

http://fluxible.io/api/components.html

Am I declaring my fluxible component correctly?  It errors with no initial state so it looks like it's not being called.

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchStore from '../stores/SearchStore';
import Product from './Product';

    class SearchResults extends React.Component {

        static contextTypes = {
            executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            getStore: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
        };

        static propTypes = {
            results: React.PropTypes.array
        };

        static defaultProps = {
            results:[]
        };
        getInitialState () {
            return this.getStoreState();
        }
        getStoreState () {
            return {
                results: this.context.getStore(SearchStore).getResults()
            }
        }
        componentDidMount () {
            this.context.getStore(SearchStore).addChangeListener(this._onStoreChange);
        }
        componentWillUnmount () {
            this.context.getStore(SearchStore).removeChangeListener(this._onStoreChange);
        }
        _onStoreChange () {
            this.setState(this.getStoreState());
        }


        render() {

            var main;

            if (this.state && this.state.results && this.state.results.length) {
                let products = this.state.results.map(function (product) {
                    return (
                        <Product
                            key={product.id}
                            imageUrl={product.image_url_large}
                            description={product.description}
                            name={product.name}
                            maxPrice={product.price_max}
                            minPrice={product.price_min}
                        />
                    );
                }, this);

                main = (
                    <section id="results">
                        <ul id="todo-list">
                            {products}
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                );
            }

            return (
                <div>
                    <header id="header">
                        <h1>Search Results</h1>
                    </header>
                    {main}
                </div>
            );
        }

    }


    export default SearchResults;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to use getInitialState using the ES6 class style for React Components.  Instead, initial state belongs in the constructor.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

> The API is similar to React.createClass with the exception of getInitialState. Instead of providing a separate getInitialState method, you set up your own state property in the constructor.

You may also want to check out `connectToStores` instead of trying to wire it up to the store the way you are now, as well.
 http://fluxible.io/addons/connectToStores.html

Comment: That's what I thought, but the example on "Accessing Stores" here http://fluxible.io/api/components.html implements the getInitialState() function even though it's extending a class.  Is that an error in their docs?

Comment: also - if I want to use the decorator pattern, do I have to import or configure something in the environment?  I'm getting  a syntax error using the @ decorator

Comment: If you want to use the decorator you will need to have babel in stage-1
`{
  "presets": ["stage-1"]
}` in your babelrc

Comment: as for the fluxible docs.  This is not true.  They are implementing getStoreState, not getInitialState

Comment: He just updated the fluxible docs this morning as per the answer below.  It was using getInitialState until just now.

Comment: oh.  i see.  all's well then :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided it so

```
class Tooltip extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
             handleOutsideClick: this.handleOutsideClick.bind(this)
        };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
         window.addEventListener('click', this.state.handleOutsideClick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
         window.removeEventListener('click', this.state.handleOutsideClick);
    }
}
```